# Is it possible to discover variables in scope without knowing their names?

Tags: reflection, groovy, scope

I have been given a large Java & Groovy based system. When the groovy scripts are executed the Java places some useful variables in scope for the Groovy to interact with. Trouble is that I don't know what these variables are or even their names. Is there a way that I can find out by writing Groovy that inspects it's own scope and outputs the the names of variables it finds?

Once I have a variable by name I can use reflection on it to find out anything else I need.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems the magic is in `binding.getVariables()`

I found a function where the return value got turned into something I could see and used this:

```
def r = [:]
binding.getVariables().entrySet().each {
    r[it.key] = it.value.getClass().getName()
}
```

which returns a map of all of the variables I was looking for and their types.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
def env = System.getenv()
//Print all the environment variables.
env.each{
     println it
}
```

Comment: Good shout. It seems 'environment' was the wrong word for me to use in my question. I think 'scope' is a better choice.